# Button inside Update Panel not working from Content Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I am facing issue with update panel inside content page, my control such as button events dont fire if i put them inside the UpdatePanel on content page.

Below is the structure of my Master & Content Page.

ON Master page i am using Update Panel with for email registration whcih is working fine on Master page. But when i try to add update Panel on content/child page then button event doesnt fire for soem reason. I have looked at  several examples but nothing seems to work.

Below is the structure of both page not sure what i am doing wrong

**MASTER PAGE**

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MainMP.master.cs" Inherits="MainMP" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <!--  -->
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
         <!--  -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>



 <!-- Page Content-->
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    <!-- Page Content -->

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**CONTENT PAGE**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMP.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Blog.aspx.cs" Inherits="Blog" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

<!-- Some Page content ...... -->

          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updxxxx" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
               <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" >
                     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your button is outside the update panel,  then you need to set that button as a trigger in you update panel for it to initiate postback.

Comment: I have tried Trigger also but my button is inside Update Panel, I event tried this simple exmple it is not even working http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/ajax-updapanel-control-with-triggers.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you can test as follow,and then add the AjaxControlToolkit.

Master:

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SiteTest.master.cs" Inherits="ZeroBig.m_test.SiteTest" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>

  <head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Page:

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/m_test/SiteTest.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ZeroBig.m_test.WebForm1" %>
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updxxxx" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </asp:Content>
```

Page.cs

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "hello";
    }
}
```

If you click the button, the label text changed to "hello" , the panel is updated. [image: test image]

Comment: I sorted the issue, issue was due to some conflict with js files included after placing the files in proper place and it worked. I kept important js file below script manager in MasterPage and custom.js file at the end of page. also upgraded jQuery Nuget to the version i was using.